# Magento Connect Upload: Save release failed

Tags: magento

We developed new release of one of our extension. However when I try to upload to Magento Connect I'm getting only

**An error occurred during upload to channel MagentoConnect 1.0: Saving
release failed .**

All information about new release (release title, releas notes etc.) are filled correctly, but upload fails. I upload PEAR version 1.0 (for Magento 1.5 and bellow) made by Magento Pacakge Manager, that is integrated in Magento. I'm not able to investigate what is wrong. Previous releases work fine. I was looking for it on Google, but no success. Is there anyone who would meet with similar issue?

It is strange behaviour. If package.xml was wrong then server would get "Invalid package.xml" instead of "Saving release failed.". This message confuses me. Maybe a bug on Magento Connect? You know is there support contact for Magento Connect? I would try to ask him.

Many thank for any ideas how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from official Magento Connect support:

*The cause of the issues was related to the missed utf-8 support for the same of the fields.*

We have utf-8 characters in the author tag . Developers from Magento Connect fixed it. Support said:

*Issue has been resolved, so you should not have this problem anymore.*

Answer (score 0):

we found out a possible issue. After moving to new servers, there is a limitation for license field started being enforced at 20 chars instead of just silently cut the string. Now it is increased to 128. If you had long license text, can you reupload and see if it helps?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. We try to reupload but no success. We try to change licence field to "Commercial" (only 10 chars) but no success again. Is it possible that problem make XML attribute "uri"?